# Ninject não carrega as dependências. Asp.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, injeção-de-dependência, ninject

Estou usando o NinjectWebCommom trabalhar com Inject. Instalei o pacote via Nuget e automaticamente ele cria uma classe nomeada "NinjectWebCommon" na pasta App_Start, como a própria documentação diz. Preciso saber por que não esta funcionando corretamente, segue alguns trechos de código:

#### `NinjectWebCommon.cs`

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start()
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        // kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        kernel.Bind<IFooService>().To<FooService>();
    }
}
```

#### `Controller`

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly IFooService fooService;

    public FooController(IFooService fooService)
    {
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(this.fooService.All());
    }
}
```

#### Este trecho gera o seguinte erro

> Error activating IFooService No matching bindings are available, and
>   the type is not self-bindable. Activation path:
>
> 2) Injection of dependency IFooService into parameter fooService of
>   constructor of type FooController
>
> 1) Request for FooController
>
> Suggestions:
>
> 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IFooService. 
>   2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has
>   been loaded into the kernel.
>
> 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
>
> 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter
>   name matches the constructors parameter name.
>   5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path
>   and filters are correct.

Use IoC to resolve instances, but it works only in my HomeController, if I change to another controller using EXACTLY the same code (with the IoC), it generates the error again. Follows the code using the IoC.

#### Segue o trecho usando IoC:

```
private readonly IFooService fooService;

public HomeController()
{
    this.fooService = IoC.Instance.Resolve<IFooService>();
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.MyFoos = this.fooService.All();

    return View();
}
```

#### generates this error

No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

Error activating IFooService No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

> Activation path: 
>   1) Request for IFooService
>
> Suggestions:
>
> 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IFooService.
>
> 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has
>   been loaded into the kernel.
>
> 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
>
> 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter
>   name matches the constructors parameter name.
>
> 5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path
>   and filters are correct.

Comment: Quais são as dependências do `FooService`? Estão sendo injecionados também?

Comment: E lá em cimão no NinjectWebCommon.cs, tem o web activator? parece assim: `[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod...]`

Comment: Tente substituir **private readonly IFooService fooService;** por **public  IFooService FooService {get; set;}** e remova o parâmetro do construtor da classe FooController. A linha **fooService = fooService** não é necessária pois o próprio NInject irá inicializar a property com a injeção de dependência.

Comment: @UlyssesAlves fiz as modificações e não funcionou. O get; set; deixa a interface null.

Comment: E aquele erro **Error activating IFooService No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.** ainda ocorre depois dessa alteração?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves não, porém com o service null, o problema continua...

Comment: O código que você usou com comentários em inglês você tirou de algum artigo? Se sim, teria como nos passar o link pra gente poder analisar melhor?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves é parte do Nuget, ele instala automaticamente esta classe dentro do projeto, segue o link da documentação: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

Comment: @brazilianldsjaguar sim para a segunda pergunta, a primeira eu não sei te responder de certeza, mas acredito que a partir da classe usada, ele deveria resolver as outras e ele tiver.

Comment: @LuizNegrini Então, você herdou sua classe MvcApplication de NinjectHttpApplication, como mostra na página? **public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication**

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26461/discussion-between-ulysses-alves-and-luiz-negrini).

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema carregando todos os "NinjectModule" da hierarquia da minha aplicação.

Achava que era suficiente carregando apenas o modulo principal, então criei um outro método statico dentro do "NinjectWebCommon" apenas para separar as responsabilidades e organizar o código. Segue abaixo o código usado:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new Repository(), new Service(), new ValidationAndBusinessRules());
```

onde carrego todos os respectivos Repositorios, Services e Validators na criação do Kernel.

```
 private static void RegisterObrigatoryServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IIdentityProvider>().To<ServiceIdentityProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<Guid>().ToMethod(ctx => default(Guid)).Named("CurrentProcessId");
            kernel.Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx =>
            {
                SessionPoolManager.Update();

                Guid processId = kernel.Get<Guid>("CurrentProcessId", new Parameter[] { });

                if (processId == default(Guid))
                {
                    return SessionFactoryBuilder.SessionFactory(kernel.Get<IIdentityProvider>()).OpenSession();
                }
                else
                {
                    ISession session = SessionPoolManager.Get(processId);
                    if (session == null)
                    {
                        session = SessionFactoryBuilder.SessionFactory(kernel.Get<IIdentityProvider>()).OpenSession();
                        SessionPoolManager.Register(processId, session);
                    }

                    return session;
                }
            });
        }
```

método criado por mim dentro do NinjectWebCommon como mencionado acima, somente para registrar as dependencias obrigatórias.

Todo este código basicamente é nativo e vem inserido dentro do pacote Nuget Ninject.MVC4 (instalado via Console Package Manager dentro do Visual Studio). Este pacote insere uma classe no diretório App_Start chamada "NinjectWebCommon", e é la que realizei estas alterações.

o controler fica definido como manda a documentação do pacote, da seguinte forma:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private readonly IFooService fooService;

            public HomeController(IFooService fooService)
            {
                this.fooService = fooService; //Daqui para frente é possível usar normalmente o service.
            }
        }
```